Can I specify a maven profile in Eclipse Spring Boot Dashoard to change dependencies by Run Configuration?
I have a Spring Boot Maven web application (app.war) that has a dependency on library lib.jar. lib.jar is published with two classifiers:

lib-release.jar which is obfuscated with proguard
lib-debug.jar which is not obfuscated and has additional loggers

I would like to be able to specify which classifier to use as a property/config on the Boot Dashboard Run Configuration, rather than editing the POM which is the only way I've been able to get it to work. Is this possible?
Currently, the pom.xml is configured to use the release jar by default so that the obfuscated version is used, but we have a debug profile that we can use when packaging to create a war with the debug lib e.g.: mvn clean package -Pdebug. Example:
<properties>
    <lib.classifier>release<lib.classifier>
<properties> 
...
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>debug</id>
    <properties>
      <lib.classifier>debug</lib.classifier>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>libgrp</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>${lib.classifier}</classifier>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

This works fine for packaging, but the "Boot Dashboard" in eclipse only seems to use the default property and has ignored all attempts by me to switch the Maven profile using parameters. The Boot Dashboard must be resolving the dependices when it is triggered, but is there a way that I can specify a Maven property, or even just explicitly set the property without modifying the pom.xml? I have tried specifying Pdebug, -Dlib.classifier=debug and even --lib.classifier=debug which was a long shot since that is just a Spring style property rather than Maven.
Additional info:

the app uses Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE which is old, but forced upon us by the environment that we have to run in


I think the answer is yes. It's important to keep in mind that you actually have 2 different sets of profiles in play. Maven profiles come into play at build-time, while spring profiles come into play at runtime.
You can definitely use maven profiles to customize dependencies and other aspects of the pom at build time. Your build job (whatever runs the mvn command) would need to invoke the appropriate maven profile to build (using mvn -P) with the desired dependencies. See the maven build profile documentation for information about how to use profile-specific dependencies, plugins, etc.
In addition, Spring profiles can be used to update the runtime behavior of your already built artifact. The Spring profile documentation describes how you can code and then start a Spring application using profiles that selects profile-specific beans and configurations. This is very useful when building an artifact that must then be tested and deployed to different environments (dev, staging, qa, production, etc). In each case, there is a single compiled artifact (jar, war, ear) that is smart enough to configure itself for the desired environment using the active spring profile.
